# track milestone changes updating cells at weekly intervals

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks linked together showing milestones of a program.  The source workbook has one column to input milestone dates.  The destination workbook has columns in weekly intervals to track milestone dates at each week of the program.  The destination workbook is to be updated each week (when the source workbook is updated) and dates populated in the respective columns.   I want the destination workbook to track the changes to milestone dates in each respective column i.e. on 1 Jan source workbook is updated, and dates are populated in the 1 Jan column in the destination workbook. On 7 Jan, milestone dates are updated in the source workbook again (the date from 1 Jan is overwritten) and these dates are populated in the 7 Jan column in the destination folder (without changing the dates recorded for the previous week, 1 Jan).

I am using excel 2016. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Exactly how are the workbooks "linked together"?

Comment: I would be useful to see an example of the data to get a better idea of what you're trying yo achieve.  You could use conditional formatting on the sheet that has all the data to highlight the dates if they are delayed or brought forward from the previous week.